# Very low network speed in wifi - ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I have been experiencing slow download speeds with my Ubuntu installation, Windows and Mac on other devices are getting much better rates. I do not have another Ubuntu system to compare. Here is the paste from wirelessinfo script : http://paste.ubuntu.com/24737006/

Comment: You check the speed using a live DVD/USB session, if that's an option for you.

Comment: @grooveplex I tried something else, I tried switching to lan on the same connection and got 12 Mbps on fast.com over the 100-200 Kbps I was getting through wifi.

Comment: that sounds annoying. I hope someone knows what's up. +1

Answer (score 0):

First off, are you having issues with all of the wireless network listed in your script output, or only some of them? If some, then limiting the question will certainly help in troubleshooting.

Assuming your slow throughput issue is for all networks listed, from your script, I see two possible reasons for the slow throughput on your wifi link:

- Power management is enabled on your wireless hardware
- High Tx retries, suggesting incorrect hardware configuration

Power management shouldn't be a reason for slow throughput, but you might consider testing whether it has any impact on performance, and if so, to what degree. To disable power management for your wifi hardware:

`sudo iwconfig wlo1 power off`

Again, this generally shouldn't pose a significant performance issue, but it's worth testing to see if this is a factor in your particular case.

Regarding Tx retries, you'll see in your script output that `Tx excessive retries` is somewhat high at 423 (a good link generally has a handful of retries), though this is a cumulative value, so if your link was up for hours before running this script, then I'd worry less than if the link was up for just a minute or so.

There are many reasons for excessive Tx retries, so you may want to Google further to limit the possibilities. From there, we might be able to zero in on the specific cause of your slow throughput.

Rich

Comment: I was able to get a better speed in my system by changing to wicd from network manager. While the ui is a bit off, I still get better speeds on wicd, still notably slower than what others are getting on their machines.